# Different considerations when defining 3D bins vs 1D bins for a histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, histogram

I'm trying to create a 3D histogram of some data I have but I think there must be something wrong with how I'm defining the bins because I'm getting a lot of empty marginal histograms. The following is how I'm creating the histogram and how I'm checking the values --

```
# Hard boundaries for the cube 
param1_range = [0, 6]
param2_range = [-2, +0.5]
param3_range = [0, 2]

d_param1 = 0.5
param1_bins = np.arange(param1_range[0], param1_range[1], d_param1)
N_param1_bins = len(d_param1) - 1

d_param2 = 0.5
param2_bins = np.arange(param2_range[0], param2_range[1], d_param2)
N_param2_bins = len(d_param2) - 1

d_param3 = 0.25
param3_bins = np.arange(param3_range[0], param3_range[1], d_param3)
N_param3_bins = len(d_param3) - 1


empty_param1, empty_param2, empty_param3 = 0, 0, 0 
cube_full = np.zeros((Nobs, N_param1_bins, N_param2_bins, N_param3_bins))
for i in range(Nobs):
    tmp = np.vstack((param1_data[i,:], param2_data[i,:], param3_data[i,:])).T
    hist, _ = np.histogramdd(tmp[:,:],
                             bins=[param1_bins, param2_bins, param3_bins], 
                             density=True)
    cube_full[i,:,:,:] = hist

    if np.all(hist[:,0,0] == 0.):
              empty_param1 = empty_param1 + 1
    if np.all(hist[0,:,0] == 0.):
              empty_param2 = empty_param2 + 1
    if np.all(hist[0,0,:] == 0.):
              empty_param3 = empty_param3 + 1

print(empty_param1/Nobs, empty_param2/Nobs, empty_param3/Nobs)
```

About half of the marginal histograms for "param1" are empty and nearly all for "param2" and "param3".

I determined the parameter ranges from looking at my data. I also created 1D histograms for the different parameters using these same ranges and don't get empty bins like when I try to make the 3D histogram. Is there some additional consideration that I'm missing when defining 3D bins versus 1D bins?

Comment: You're saying "marginal histograms"  The first `np.all` asks "how many points have param2 < -1.5 and param3 < 0.25".  You're convinced such points exist?

Comment: Would you mind explaining more in what way the first np.all is selecting for param2 < -1.5 and param3 < 0.25?

Comment: `hist[:,0:0]` will contain all the points where the Y and Z coordinates went into the zero-th bin.  The zero-th bin for Y is -2 to -1.5,  The zero-th bin for Z is 0 to 0.25.  If there are no points where -2 < Y < -1.5   AND   0 < Z < 0.25, then all those bins would be 0.

Comment: `hist[0,0,0]` contains the count of points where X < .5, Y < -1.5, and Z < 0.25.  `hist[1,0,0]` contains the count of points where .5 <= X < 1.0, Y < -1.5, and Z < 0.25.  Right?  (I might have <= and < switched, but that's a detail.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining more. I must be misunderstanding the data structure of "hist". What I'm trying to do is select the 1D histograms (what I mean by "marginal") along the different axes. Do you have any suggestions for doing that? And, just to check, what I'm trying to do with histogramdd is define the 3D bins using the param123_ranges and get the amplitudes over the grid points. Is that what histogramdd is actually doing?

Comment: If you want three 1D histograms, then you should do three separate 1D histograms, rather than try to do data reduction on a 3D histogram.  Histograms are easy and cheap.

Comment: I need the 3D histogram. Is there no way to slice the 3D histogram along the different axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting here, but from the comments, I THINK what you want is this:

```
    sum1 = np.sum(hist, (1,2))
    if np.all(sum1) == 0:
        empty_param1 += 1
    sum2 = np.sum(hist, (0,2))
    sum3 = np.sum(hist, (0,1))
```

This essentially produces the 1D histograms from the 3D data.  If I've still missed the mark, maybe you can provide a example using smaller matrices.

Example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(125).reshape((5,5,5))
>>> x
array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
        [  5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
        [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
        [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
        [ 20,  21,  22,  23,  24]],

       [[ 25,  26,  27,  28,  29],
        [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34],
        [ 35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
        [ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44],
        [ 45,  46,  47,  48,  49]],

       [[ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54],
        [ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59],
        [ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64],
        [ 65,  66,  67,  68,  69],
        [ 70,  71,  72,  73,  74]],

       [[ 75,  76,  77,  78,  79],
        [ 80,  81,  82,  83,  84],
        [ 85,  86,  87,  88,  89],
        [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94],
        [ 95,  96,  97,  98,  99]],

       [[100, 101, 102, 103, 104],
        [105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
        [110, 111, 112, 113, 114],
        [115, 116, 117, 118, 119],
        [120, 121, 122, 123, 124]]])
>>> np.sum(x,(1,2))
array([ 300,  925, 1550, 2175, 2800])
>>> np.sum(x,(0,2))
array([1300, 1425, 1550, 1675, 1800])
>>> np.sum(x,(0,1))
array([1500, 1525, 1550, 1575, 1600])
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted and it looks like there was nothing wrong with how I was defining the grid after all!

Comment: If you will allow me to be a bit snarky, what you'll end up with is EXACTLY the same as the 1D histograms that I suggested above...

Comment: I won't actually be using the 1D histograms, I need the amplitude of my data over the 3D grid. But I have to do some (not quite, but you can think of it as) unit conversions on the binned data. When I tried to do  it originally I was getting a lot of garbage because my slices of the ndarray were coming up empty. Which is why I thought there might be something wrong with my grid definitions but you demonstrated that my slicing was wrong. So, thanks again!